# Remove Django tests using setup.py bdist_rpm

Tags: python, django, rpm, setuptools, setup.py

I'm trying to remove all of the tests directories as well as the tests.py files when creating an RPM from a setup.py file using bdist_rpm.  I have tried excluding it from find_packages(), but it only removes tests packages, which is only half the issue.  any tests.py files remain in packages that don't have a tests directory.  How can I remove both tests directories and tests.py files?  Here is my setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages                                                      

setup(name='mydjangoui',
      version='1.0',
      description='A django application',
      package_dir={'':'mydjangoui'},
      packages=find_packages('mydjangoui', 
          exclude=['tests.*', '*.tests.*', '*.tests', 'tests']),
)
```

I'm building the rpm with the following command:

```
python setup.py bdist_rpm
```

There is an app (`marketing`) that contains tests.py, tests.pyo, tests.pyc as well as some valid models.py and views.py files.  I want to remove the tests.py[o|c] files from this app before the RPM is created.

Output from `find_packages(exclude=['*tests*'])`

```
>>> find_packages(exclude=['*tests*'])
['motd', 'assessment', 'account', 'platform', 'custom', 'catalog', 'utils', 'asset', 'editors', 'scheduler', 'base', 'marketing', 'results']
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `find_packages(exclude=['*tests*'])`?

Comment: I have added the output above and some other details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Final update solving the problem:**

Use the following `find_packages()` call to ignore any module or sub module named `tests`:

```
setup(name='mydjangoapp',
  version='1.0',
  description='A django app',
  package_dir={'':'mock'},
  packages=find_packages('mock', exclude=['tests', '*.tests']),
)
```

We might still have files named `tests.py` in our resulting RPM, though.

To purge these, create a file named `MANIFEST.in` inside your project folder and add the following line to it which tells `distutils` to ignore files named `tests.py` in any folder:

```
recursive-exclude * tests.py
```

This will not include, e.g., `marketing/tests.py` anymore.

If you get warnings about non-existing, previously defined files, clean up the generated files before re-creating the RPM package:

```
python setup.py clean --all
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: That does not appear to work.  That includes both the tests directory as well as any tests.py

Comment: Thanks for the more detailed explanation, however, this is still including tests from my own apps.  When I look at the RPM after it is built, I still see the following is included: /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/marketing/tests.py,                                                                                                     
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/marketing/tests.pyc,                                                                                            
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/marketing/tests.pyo.  I'm wanting to make sure these are removed as well.

Comment: I miscommunicated.  'django' is simply a directory I have created that hosts my django app. It's not the actual django framework.  'marketing' is an app I have under this directory. I'll update the original question to make it easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks for the update. However, marketing/tests.py is still included.  I even tried ['tests', '*.tests', '*tests*'].  It just really wants to keep those tests in the RPM!  What code would you like to see that may help?

Comment: @intargc: you have to create a `MANIFEST.in` file, then it should work out as expected...

Comment: I've been trying that route too. Apparently I need to read more about `MANIFEST.in` because those files still show up and I get this from the build: `warning: no previously-included files found matching '*.tests.py*' warning: no previously-included files found matching '*tests*' warning: no previously-included files found matching '*tests.*' warning: no previously-included files found matching '*.tests.*' warning: no previously-included files found matching 'tests.py'` I'm sure I'm missing something...

Comment: That seemed hopeful, but the same problem exists.  Same tests.py* files in the marketing app... Thank you for the persistent help!

Comment: Unfortunately, I wish I could but I cannot.  It is for work and contains proprietary code.  I understand this severely limits the amount of help that can be given to this problem.  Maybe I can make a mock project that contains similar but empty files and upload it. Let me look into this...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10186/discussion-between-cfedermann-and-intargc)